# Improve Ethernet throughput for jumbo frames

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, ethernet

We are running throughput test on the gigE of Macnica Helio board with 1GB DDR3 specification.We are now achieving 60% (Jumbo frame) throughput, however we expect higher throughput in our application.

Method of calculation as following:-

```
    (100M / time taken * 8-bit /1Gbps)*100%
```

What we did:
-Transfer 100MB using server and client code

Server(Cyclone V)
-change eth0 MTU 7500 (only achieve if we turn off tx checksum using ethtool "ethtool -K eth0 tx off" else we are just able to change the MTU up to 3500 only) then execute the server code

Client (Laptop runs UBUNTU)
-change eth0 MTU to 9000 then execute the client code and test the throughput performance using wireshark

We do try to change ipv4 setting using command below but throughput result is still the same

```
   -sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=18388608
   -sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=18388608
   -sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=1065536
   -sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=1065536
   -sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 87380 18388608
   -sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 87380 18388608
   -sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mem=18388608 18388608 18388608
   -sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1
   -sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1
```

Question

is there any method or solution to achieve higher throughput?

Is there any effect if we turn off the tx checksum?

What is the the different of tcp_congestion_control between cubic and bic and will it effect throughput performance?

Answer (score 0):

Use ntop.org's [PF_RING](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/) sockets instead of PF_INET sockets. We have been able to get up to 75% throughput with GigE Vision protocol (UDP) using Intel (e1000) NIC's, without using the NIC-specific PF_RING drivers.

AFAIK the `tcp_congestion_control` will only help you at the start of the TCP session and has no effect once the session is established.

Comment: sorry. is there any installation guide? After reading it seem like i need to compile it and insmod as a kernel module

Comment: @WWJ: The PF_RING package has good installation instructions and examples, but it does take two or three days to work through all of the example programs and understand how it works, and you do need to be adept at compiling the kernel and modules. To use it in userspace you do need some programming skills to integrate it into your applications. It's not something that you can do at the sys admin level.